# RavenDB Query Statistics server execution time in milliseconds

Tags: ravendb, long-integer, milliseconds

I am trying to print the query statistics upon execution of the given query. Particularly I am interested in execution time on server in milliseconds property. Below is my code for reference

```
void Main()
{
    var documentStore = DocumentStoreHolder.Store;
    Load_Stats(documentStore);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public static void Load_Stats(IDocumentStore documentStore)
{


using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    RavenQueryStatistics stats;
    IRavenQueryable<Order> recentOrdersQuery = from order in session.Query<Order>().Statistics(out stats) where order.Company=="companies/1" select order;
    List<Order> recentOrders = recentOrdersQuery.Take(3).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Index used was: " + stats.IndexName);
    Console.WriteLine($"Other stats : 1. Execution time on the server :  {stats.DurationMilliseconds} 2.Total number of results {stats.TotalResults} 3. The last document ETag {stats.ResultEtag} 4. The timestamp of last document indexed by the index {stats.IndexTimestamp}");
}
```

But upon repeated execution of this query I get time taken to run query on server in milliseconds as -1. I am failing to understand why it is happening so. Should I assign the result to a long variable or is it allowed to print the result as such (stats.DurationMilliseconds). TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that this is because RavenDB was able to serve the request from the client cache, instead of going to the server

Comment: Thanks Oren! I tried a different predicate which I had not used in my previous queries and I am able to get a valid result. Will explore options in client-side to disable cache for testing.